# How to remove numbers from url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url http://example.com/3-digital_marketing
I want to it like http://example.com/digital_marketing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a 3-1 rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/ 

RewriteRule ^[0-9]+-(.+?)/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# rest of rules
```

Comment: i tested this code on local server and i wrote it like below:-
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]+-(test)/?$ /$1

Comment: and my page is 87-test.php

Comment: Is your URL `http://example.com/87-test.php` OR `http://example.com/test/87-test.php`

Comment: ok see updated code. This rule must be first rule below `RewriteBase /test/` rule as shown.

Comment: yeah its working, but this code is redirecting page to test where 404 error is showing. I want only hide those numbers

Comment: Rule is doing what you wanted i.e. `/test/87-test.php` to `/test/test.php` now if that gives 404 then I cant guess that.

Comment: actually i am using that no on my page and after using this code page redirects to other url and that no is not accessible at that page

Comment: If that number is being used than you cannot really remove is completely from a URL right?